# Как объединить два запроса where (из массива) в один?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Делаю поиск(автокомплит), нужно чтобы находил название **Автошина ТЮМЕНЬ 175/70**
по запросу **шина 175**.

Делаю с помощью `ILIKE`

Как получить запрос типа `SELECT "products".* FROM "products"  WHERE (title ILIKE '%шина%') AND (title ILIKE '%175%')`

Версия **рельсов 3**, так что сделать:

```
products = Product.all
["шина", "175"].each do |word|
  products = products.where("title ILIKE ?", "%#{word}")
end
```

тоже не вариант.

или если без `Product.all`, то получиться запрос `SELECT "products".* FROM "products"  WHERE (title ILIKE '%175')`

P.S. возможно построить запрос по `SIMILAR TO`, но здесь тоже не получается.

Comment: А если собрать условие `where title ILIKE '%шина%175%'` ? Правда если ввести `175 шина`, то искомое значение найти не получится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
q = Product.arel_table[:title].matches_all(["%шина%", "%175%"])
products = Product.where(q)
```

Дает такой запрос `SELECT "products".* FROM "products"  WHERE (("products"."title" ILIKE '%шина%' AND "products"."title" ILIKE '%175%'))`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products"  WHERE (title ILIKE '%175%') and 
"products".name in (
SELECT "products".* FROM "products"  WHERE (title ILIKE '%шина%'))
```

Вложенный запрос выберет все названия с `"шина"`, а второй запрос отфильтрует уже по названию `"175"`.